# Adobe Captivate 3 Typing Sound viewing a recording

Tags: adobe, adobe-captivate

I am using Adobe Captivate 3 and am having trouble disabling the typing noise when using a recording.  Sometimes when I have this 'feature' disabled and make a recording, it doesn't make the typing sound, but when I publish the project, the typing sound returns.  Also, I have other projects I am working on where the typing sound wasn't initially disabled during the recording and I can't get it to stop making that typing noise.

Any suggestions on how to disable the typing sound permanently within a new or existing Captivate project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple items from some searching about:

Adobe.com : [Setting keyboard tap sounds](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Captivate/3.0/05_audio_17.html)

> If you do not like the tapping sounds in your finished project, use the following procedure to remove them. The tapping sound is a project-level setting, so the sound either plays on all slides or is removed from all slides.

[Adobe Captivate 3: Recorded Keystrokes Got You Re-Recording? Not Anymore!](http://iconlogic.blogs.com/weblog/2007/09/adobe-captiva-3.html)

Long post on this one, with a couple options.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the clicking sounds just before publishing (Captivate 3).  Click Publish, then click Preferences then un-check "Play tap audio for recorded type when project is generated".  This worked for me.